# Dummy values of serialized variable

Tags: java, string, serialization, integer, transient

Why default values as Zero are displayed for transient variables in Java?

How does it know that the value should be `0` for `integer` and `null` for `String`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It knows that because that's [how it's specified](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/datatypes.html). Default value for `int` is 0, and default value for `String` is null.

Answer (score 1):

From [**DOCS**](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/datatypes.html)

> It's not always necessary to assign a value when a field is declared. Fields that are declared but not initialized will be set to a reasonable default by the compiler. Generally speaking, this default will be zero or null, depending on the data type.

Answer (score 0):

Default value of an **int is 0** and a **String is null**

Answer (score 0):

The default values for fields is defined by the JLS.  Making it transient gives a *hint* that it won't be set and thus have the default value.

Answer (score 0):

> How does it know that the value should be 0 for integer and null for String?

Because that's the [default, defined in the Java Language Specification](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-4.html#jls-4.12.5).